# Is it possible that my python code for calculating numerical partial derivatives can be further simplified?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numerical-methods, derivative

I want to compute the 1st-order partial derivatives of a 3D Cartesian mesh with shape (Nmesh, Nmesh, Nmesh), e.g. Nmesh=512 by the fourth-order accuracy scheme, i.e.

f'(n) = 2*(f(n+1)-f(n-1))/(3*dh) - (f(n+2)-f(n-2))/(12*dh) .

For this end, I wrote a Python function as shown below. However, I see that some rows are very similar between different conditional branches. So can I further simplify this function?

```
import numpy as np

def partial( arr, Nmesh, dh, axis=0 ):
    ''' 
    The partial derivative of the 3D Cartesian mesh with periodic
    boundary conditions, computed by the fourth-order accuracy scheme.
    '''
    dh1 = 2/(3*dh)
    dh2 = -1/(12*dh)

    if (axis==0):
        arr_  = np.pad(arr, [(2,2), (0,0), (0,0)], mode='wrap')
        diff1 = arr_[3:Nmesh+3,:,:] - arr_[1:Nmesh+1,:,:]
        diff2 = arr_[4:Nmesh+4,:,:] - arr_[0:Nmesh,:,:]
        return dh1*diff1 + dh2*diff2
    elif (axis==1):
        arr_  = np.pad(arr, [(0,0), (2,2), (0,0)], mode='wrap')
        diff1 = arr_[:,3:Nmesh+3,:] - arr_[:,1:Nmesh+1,:]
        diff2 = arr_[:,4:Nmesh+4,:] - arr_[:,0:Nmesh,:]
        return dh1*diff1 + dh2*diff2
    elif (axis==2):
        arr_  = np.pad(arr, [(0,0), (0,0), (2,2)], mode='wrap')
        diff1 = arr_[:,:,3:Nmesh+3] - arr_[:,:,1:Nmesh+1]
        diff2 = arr_[:,:,4:Nmesh+4] - arr_[:,:,0:Nmesh]
        return dh1*diff1 + dh2*diff2
```

Comment: Can you provide a clear example of input and the expected output to test your function? Why don't you just write **one** case on a fixed axis and pre-/post-process the array to reshape with the correct dimension?

Comment: I don't see any repetition, except for the return line, which may be pulled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [mozway's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77086838/is-it-possible-that-my-python-code-for-calculating-numerical-partial-derivatives/77089405#comment135895485_77086838), you could use the [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy-swapaxes) function to do something like:

```
import numpy as np

def partial(arr, Nmesh, dh, axis=0):
    ''' 
    The partial derivative of the 3D Cartesian mesh with periodic
    boundary conditions, computed by the fourth-order accuracy scheme.
    '''

    dh1 = 2/(3*dh)
    dh2 = -1/(12*dh)

    # use swapaxes to put required axis first
    arr_ = np.pad(
        np.swapaxes(arr, axis, 0), [(2, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0)], mode="wrap"
    )

    diff1 = arr_[3:Nmesh + 3,:,:] - arr_[1:Nmesh + 1,:,:]
    diff2 = arr_[4:Nmesh + 4,:,:] - arr_[0:Nmesh,:,:]

    # swap axes back on return
    return np.swapaxes(dh1*diff1 + dh2*diff2, 0, axis)
```